# Typescript compilation date type error

Tags: typescript

Working with typescript 1.4 I'm having funny errors on the following code lines :

```
var dateFrom:Date;
var dateTo:Date;
if(typeof discount.dateFrom ===  "string"){
    dateFrom = new Date(discount.dateFrom); // Line 362
} else {
    dateFrom = discount.dateFrom;
}

if(typeof discount.dateTo ===  "string"){
    dateTo = new Date(<string>discount.dateTo); // Line 368
} else {
    dateTo = discount.dateTo;
}
```

The transpiler returns the following:

```
[FULL_PATH]/Quotation.ts(362,37): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
[FULL_PATH]/Quotation.ts(368,35): error TS2352: Neither type 'Date' nor type 'string' is assignable to the other.
```

The difference from line 362 and 368 are two cases I tried to fix the issue.

I used this gimmic at other place in the code, and it worked fine.

I'm including the definition of the Date constructor from lib.d.ts for reference :

```
new (): Date;
new (value: number): Date;
new (value: string): Date;
new (year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): Date;
(): string;
```

Comment: The error in line #362 seems obvious... the constructor argument expects a `string` or a `number`, but you are passing it another `Date`. Unless `discount.dateFrom` is not the same as the variable declared at the top?

Comment: @danludwig I guess was that line 368 should fix the issue

Comment: The problem with line #368 is that there is no known conversion from `Date` to `string`. It's like typescript telling you that is an invalid cast. If it is possible for the runtime type of `discount.dateFrom` or `discount.dateTo` to be `string`, then you should declare them as `any` instead of as `Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `discount.dateFrom` is a union type such as `string|Date`, it looks like you're trying to use a type guard on the property of an object, not on a plain local variable. That's not supported:

```
if (typeof discount.dateFrom === "string") {
    // This doesn't change the type of discount.dateFrom
}
```

However, if you write:

```
var dateFromProp = discount.dateFrom;
if (typeof dateFromProp === "string") {
    // dateFromProp is a string in this scope
}
```

Then should work.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know you could do this. So is this a "union type"? `dateFromProp` does not get its type inferred from the type of `discount.dateFrom`? Which version of TS introduced union types, or have they been hiding there all along?

Comment: @danludwig the union type got introduce in 1.4 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @danludwig the known convertor from `date` to `string` is `.toString()`

```
if(typeof discount.dateTo ===  "string"){
    dateTo = new Date(discount.dateTo.toString());
} else {
    dateTo = discount.dateTo;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is if `typeof discount.dateTo === 'string'`, you should not have to call `.toString()` on it. If it's possible for `discount.dateTo` to be either `string` or `Date`, then it should be declared as `any`.

Comment: @danludwig - or a union type, in which case the OP's code can be fixed to be fully statically typed without resorting to `any`.